# Conditionally chaining array methods

Tags: javascript

How do I make the array methods optional?

Leets say I have this code but I want to `filter` or `map` optional

```
const ages = data
  .filter(isDog)
  .map(dogYears)
  .reduce(sum);
```

So I will do something like

```
let result

if(useFilter) {
  result = data.filter(isDog)
}

result
  .map(dogYears)
  .reduce(sum);
```

I know there should be a more compact and SOLID way of doing it

Comment: `.filter(x => useFilter ? isDog(x) : true)`

Comment: Depends on how concerned you are with performance. Using the `if()` will be more performant since you won't have extra loops to perform when conditions don't require them

Answer (score 6):

You could use the ternary operator to conditionally transform the initial array, in a single line, without any reassignment:

```
// const result = [ ... ]

const output = (useFilter ? result.filter(isDog) : result)
  .map(dogYears)
  .reduce(sum);
```